# Compare two database table rows and insert

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am working on a project where my requirement is just update the database from local server to the destination server (all tables, views, functions, rows and stored procedures).

Now I want to compare the local database table with the destination database table and insert the newly inserted rows from local database to the destination table.

E.g. :  I have a database `dbsource` and `dbDestination` and both contain a table `table1`. Now I insert new rows into `dbsource.table1`.

Now I want to compare both database tables and insert the new rows into the destination table.

Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel?? There are lots of commercial applications out there that already do this for you:

- [Red-Gate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)
- [ApexSQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx)

Comment: But why to pay money for something you can do on your own.

Comment: Might agree if more than one pair of tables were to be compared. But again, I'd rather squeze every drop of available feature than use some other third party tool. I myself use Red Gates's SQLPrompt which is an amazing plug in for SSMS because SQL Server 2005 lacks code formatting and completion features. I've no doubt that Red Gate follow the same way when they compare two tables.

Comment: Besides your own effort that also costs money - what about the fact that a third-party tool probably has much more testing in it than your own code ever will? They've probably already dealt with lots of edge cases and weird circumstances and built-in code to prevent problems.... lots of eyeballs make a product much better than you can ever do it yourself....

Comment: Beleive me, comparing two tables is not something to debug. It's got certain rules. After all you're not writing an application, you're comparing two tables data. If basic principles of relational database are applied then it's just a matter of 1 or 2 minutes. But it seems like this depends on a personal preference. I respect your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both Table1 tables have a Primary Key (unique) column here's how you can implement that. I name the PK column ID:

```
INSERT INTO DBDESTINATION.<SCHEMA_NAME>.TABLE1 
(SELECT T1.* FROM DBSOURCE.<SCHEMA_NAME>.TABLE1 AS T1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DBDESTINATION.<SCHEMA_NAME>.TABLE1 AS T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
   WHERE T2.ID IS NULL)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: what would be SCHEMA_NAME, when exec the above query getting "Incorrect syntax near '<'."

Comment: schema_name is the name of the schema that your table belogs to. By default it's dbo.so DBSOURCE.DBO.TABLE1. If you put DBO in place of schema_name (without angle brackets) you'll probably be fine